# Eclipse-plugin-dev putting a View first in a stack breaks the stack

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin, nodeclipse

In [Nodeclipse](http://www.nodeclipse.org/) UI plugin Node perspective [defines several Views](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/blob/master/org.nodeclipse.ui/plugin.xml#L261-282)

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions">
  <perspectiveExtension
        targetID="org.nodeclipse.ui.perspectives.NodePerspective">
```

when it like

```
        <view id="org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugView" 
            relative="org.eclipse.ui.console.ConsoleView" 
            relationship="stack"/>              
        <view id="org.eclipse.tcf.te.ui.terminals.TerminalsView"
            relative="org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugView"
            relationship="stack"/>
        <view id="winterwell.markdown.views.MarkdownPreview" 
            relative="org.eclipse.tcf.te.ui.terminals.TerminalsView" 
            relationship="stack"/>              
        <view id="org.eclipse.ui.views.ProblemView" 
            relative="winterwell.markdown.views.MarkdownPreview" 
            relationship="stack"/>
```

is OK. The result is

[image: 3rd]

But when I want to put TCF Terminals on the first place

```
        <view id="org.eclipse.ui.console.ConsoleView" 
            relative="org.eclipse.tcf.te.ui.terminals.TerminalsView" 
            relationship="stack"/>
        <view id="org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugView" 
            relative="org.eclipse.ui.console.ConsoleView" 
            relationship="stack"/>              
        <view id="winterwell.markdown.views.MarkdownPreview" 
            relative="org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugView" 
            relationship="stack"/>              
        <view id="org.eclipse.ui.views.ProblemView" 
            relative="winterwell.markdown.views.MarkdownPreview" 
            relationship="stack"/>
```

it breaks down into new epmty View to the right and no Terminal View

[image]

UPDATE: I tried

```
        <view id="org.eclipse.tcf.te.ui.terminals.TerminalsView"
             relative="org.eclipse.ui.editorss"
             relationship="bottom"/>
        <view id="org.eclipse.ui.console.ConsoleView" 
            relative="org.eclipse.tcf.te.ui.terminals.TerminalsView" 
            relationship="stack"/>
        <view id="org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugView" 
            relative="org.eclipse.ui.console.ConsoleView" 
            relationship="stack"/>
        <view id="winterwell.markdown.views.MarkdownPreview" 
            relative="org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugView" 
            relationship="stack"/>              
        <view id="org.eclipse.ui.views.ProblemView" 
            relative="winterwell.markdown.views.MarkdownPreview" 
            relationship="stack"/>   
        <view id="org.eclipse.pde.runtime.LogView" 
            relative="org.eclipse.ui.views.ProblemView" 
            relationship="stack"/>
```

as advised by Uwe Stieber in https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=454884#c3

But the result is putting View stack under editor but not in the South section:

[image: c3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As later advised by Uwe Stieber, solved by using [NodePerspective.java](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/blob/master/org.nodeclipse.ui/src/org/nodeclipse/ui/perspectives/NodePerspective.java)

```
    IFolderLayout rightBottom = factory.createFolder("rightBottom", IPageLayout.BOTTOM, 0.75f, factory.getEditorArea());// NON-NLS-1
    if (viewRegistry.find(ID_TERMINALS_VIEW) != null){
        rightBottom.addView(ID_TERMINALS_VIEW);        
    }
    rightBottom.addView(IConsoleConstants.ID_CONSOLE_VIEW);
    rightBottom.addView(ID_DEBUG_VIEW);
    if (viewRegistry.find(ID_MARKDOWN_VIEW) != null){
        rightBottom.addView(ID_MARKDOWN_VIEW); 
    }
    if (viewRegistry.find(ID_GFM_VIEW) != null){
        rightBottom.addView(ID_GFM_VIEW);        
    }
    rightBottom.addView(IPageLayout.ID_PROBLEM_VIEW);
    if (viewRegistry.find(ID_LOG_VIEW) != null){
        rightBottom.addView(ID_LOG_VIEW);        
    }
```